# How to record voice by Chrome's HTML5 feature?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, voice-recording

Chrome 11 supports voice recording by `<intput type="text" x-webkit-speech />`
But what's passed to server ? what's the format ?

Any server sample code ?
And ... how to playback the recorded file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Google Chrome doesn't support voice recording, but speech recognition and the speech recognition is done server-side.

Therefore you can't record the voice and play it later, unless you edit the chromium source code, but it will work only on modified version of the browser.

Comment: Thanks , I think I have to look for flash solutions.